# Finding mail with Lotus Notes 7

Tags: lotus-notes

I did some reorganisation of my mail in Lotus Notes 7 this mornign, and seem to have lost some in the process.

Not knowing Notes very well, I have two questions:

- if I selected some mail in the Inbox using the check-column, and dragged that mail into a folder, then selected some more mail in the Inbox, and hit the `Del` key, will the group of emails that were dragged into the other folder be deleted too, because I didn't unselect them?
- is there a way to search in all folders, rather than just the current folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No, the moved documents get unselected, so they shouldn't have been deleted.
- Use Full-text search (open your mail db > View > Toolbar > Search)

For any other database (other than mail db), open Application properties > go to sixth (Full Text) tab > select `Create index`.

Note that you have to be at least Designer in ACL to manipulate (create, change its properties, delete) db's full-text index.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to your all document view.  Choose View-->Search this view, which will add a toolbar across the top that you can use to search.  If your database isn't fulltext indexed, this search won't work well/fast.

You can also sort by column, and just click in the view to start typing.  This is relatively fast as long as you have it sorted by the column you are trying to search for.  IE: if you are searching for a name, sort on the name column.

You can also hit control-f and search that way, the control-f search is the least useful in my experience.